# Angularjs - how to assign functions to nested elements in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and i am not able to figure this issue.

Directive

```
app.directive('rating', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        maxStars: '=',

    },


    link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            scope.stars = [];
            for(var i=0;i<scope.maxStars;i++) {
                scope.stars.push(i);
            }

            iElement.bind('mouseenter', function(event) {

                scope.$apply(function(){
                    angular.forEach(iElement.children(),function(div){
                        angular.forEach(div.children,function(span){
                          span.addClass('rating-star-enabled'); //error addClass is not a function
                        });
                    });
                });
            });

    },
    templateUrl:'rating/rating.html'
};
}]);
```

Directive template

```
<div class="review-star">

   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record" ng-repeat="star in stars"></span>

</div>
```

Directive

```
<rating max-stars="5"></rating>
```

and i get the error addClass is not function. Its not just for addClass, if i try any other function it shows same error. if i log it in console i can see it prints all  tags. So its accessing the elements properly. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `angular.forEach()` over `iElement.children()`, you're iterating over an array of raw DOM elements (which is why you need to use `div.children` instead of `div.children()` in the inner `angular.forEach()`). You need to turn `span` (also a raw DOM element) into a jqLite object before you can call `addClass()`...

```
scope.$apply(function(){
    angular.forEach(iElement.children(),function(div){
        angular.forEach(div.children,function(span){
          angular.element(span).addClass('rating-star-enabled');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
angular.forEach(div.children,function(span){

    var a = angular.element(span);                      
    a.addClass('rating-star-enabled'); //error addClass is not a function

});
```